# NodeJs Azure Functions + Azure Service Bus Retry

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, azure, azureservicebus

I'm using Azure Functions on NodeJS with the Azure Service bus and I would like to know if there's a way to set an interval when you get an error, at the moment it will keep repeating until it reaches the queue max size every 1 second.

I've tried using `retryOptions` on `host.json` but it does nothing:

[image: Property retryOptions is not allowed]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#retry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The retryOptions are only available if you are using the Service Bus extension 5.0.0+
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#additional-settings-for-version-5x

Comment: How to specify version 5x?

Comment: How to install latest extension , it is still not affecting for me even after mentioning as per above link

Comment: How to install it is described in the same doc, if you are having issues with that please open a support ticket.

Comment: ok i have added question on azure commnunity however meanwhile if it can be checked that below  command that I am using is this correct  ? or something else can be used ? - func extensions install --package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus --version 5.0.1