# Service bus extension could not be installed node js via func insall command

Tags: azure

[image]

```js
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "clientRetryOptions":{
          "mode": "exponential",
          "tryTimeout": "00:01:00",
          "delay": "00:00:00.80",
          "maxDelay": "00:01:00",
          "maxRetries": 3
      },
      "prefetchCount": 0,
      "transportType": "amqpWebSockets",
      "webProxy": "https://proxyserver:8080",
      "autoCompleteMessages": true,
      "maxAutoLockRenewalDuration": "00:05:00",
      "maxConcurrentCalls": 16,
      "maxConcurrentSessions": 8,
      "maxMessageBatchSize": 1000,
      "minMessageBatchSize": 1,
      "maxBatchWaitTime": "00:00:30",
      "sessionIdleTimeout": "00:01:00",
      "enableCrossEntityTransactions": false
  }
  },
  "concurrency": {
    "dynamicConcurrencyEnabled": true,
    "snapshotPersistenceEnabled": true
  },

  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  }
}
```

I want to configure retry and other options in azure function for service bus queue trigger , however i understand that for that we need latest service bus extension but for that when I am trying to install via func cli

func extensions install --package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus --version 5.0.1

Pasting below error , what is missing please suggest

```
PS C:\projects\javascript\azure-function-queue-trigger> func extensions install --package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus --version 5.0.1
  Determining projects to restore...
  Writing C:\Users\Vaibhav Mittal\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpBA7C.tmp
info : X.509 certificate chain validation will use the default trust store selected by .NET.
info : X.509 certificate chain validation will use the default trust store selected by .NET.
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus' into project 'C:\projects\javascript\azure-function-queue-trigger\extensions.csproj'.
info : Restoring packages for C:\projects\javascript\azure-function-queue-trigger\extensions.csproj...
error: NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator (>= 1.1.3)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'.
error: NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus (>= 5.0.1)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'.
error: NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref (= 3.1.10)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'.
error: NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref (= 3.1.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'.
error: NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref (= 3.1.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'.
error: Package 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus' is incompatible with 'all' frameworks in project 'C:\projects\javascript\azure-function-queue-trigger\extensions.csproj'.


MSBuild version 17.3.2+561848881 for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
C:\projects\javascript\azure-function-queue-trigger\extensions.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator (>= 1.1.3)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'.
C:\projects\javascript\azure-function-queue-trigger\extensions.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref (= 3.1.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'.
C:\projects\javascript\azure-function-queue-trigger\extensions.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref (= 3.1.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'.
C:\projects\javascript\azure-function-queue-trigger\extensions.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref (= 3.1.10)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'.
  Failed to restore C:\projects\javascript\azure-function-queue-trigger\extensions.csproj (in 87 ms).

Build FAILED.

C:\projects\javascript\azure-function-queue-trigger\extensions.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator (>= 1.1.3)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'.
C:\projects\javascript\azure-function-queue-trigger\extensions.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref (= 3.1.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'.
C:\projects\javascript\azure-function-queue-trigger\extensions.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.Ref (= 3.1.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'.
C:\projects\javascript\azure-function-queue-trigger\extensions.csproj : error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.Ref (= 3.1.10)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'.
    0 Warning(s)
    4 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.65
```

Below is the host.json

Comment: Is your app nodejs function app? If yes, run the command `npm install @azure/service-bus`

Comment: Yeah That is installed already

Comment: AFAIK, `func extensions install --package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus --version 5.0.1` This command is for dotnet projects. May I know why are trying to run that command.

Comment: I have  updated my post and attached host.json file , and screen shot which says that options that I am trying to use is not valid ! ,,,,,,,,please have a look ,  then when I researched I came across through below link which says to install extension https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68717406/nodejs-azure-functions-azure-service-bus-retry

Comment: Are you still getting error even after running `npm install @azure/service-bus`?

Comment: I have updated screenshot with the , it says that "Property clientRetryOptions is not allowed." when I m hovering over "clientRetryOptions" , if we deploy with this it would fail , yeah I have installed "@azure/service-bus"